# Como passar um retorno múltiplo de uma função como parâmetros de outra?

Tags: python, funções

Por exemplo neste codigo:

```
def captar_dados():
   login = input('Login: ')
   senha = input('Senha: ')
   return login, senha
```

Aí suponhamos que eu tenha uma função de login que receba como parametros login e senha, por que eu nao consigo simplesmente fazer isso:

```
funcao_login(captar_dados())
```

Answer (score 3):

Porque são coisas distintas.

No Python não existe, de fato, um retorno múltiplo. Sempre é retornado apenas um valor, mas o que acontece nesse caso é que o valor retornado é um valor composto, ou melhor dizendo, uma tupla de dois valores.

Em questões práticas, o que fez é exatamente a mesma coisa que:

```py
def captar_dados():
   login = input('Login: ')
   senha = input('Senha: ')
   return (login, senha)
```

Assim, quando você passa o retorno dessa função para outra função que espera dois parâmetros, o que acontecerá na prática é que você define o primeiro parâmetro como sendo a tupla e nunca definirá o segundo parâmetro.

Para sua sorte, no Python existe um operador de desconstrução de tupla que resolve o seu problema. Ao fazer `*captar_dados()` você desconstruirá a tupla em dois valores distintos, definindo ambos os parâmetros que necessita:

```py
funcao_login(*captar_dados())
```

Dessa forma, os valores da tupla serão passados como parâmetros à função de forma **posicional**, então muita atenção à ordem dos valores e parâmetros.

O análogo funciona para dicionários usando o operador `**`:

```py
def captar_dados():
   login = input('Login: ')
   senha = input('Senha: ')
   return {
     'login': login,
     'senha': senha
   }

funcao_login(**captar_dados())
```

A diferença é que desconstruindo o dicionário os valores serão passados à função de forma **nomeada**, não importando a ordem de valores.